# Drupal 7 : get all node ids that has the same tag

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How can i get all node ids that has the same tag.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can use the taxonomy api. 
For example, if you know your taxonomy term id (tag id) you can use the function

[taxonomy_select_nodes](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7)

If you now the name of the tag and no the id you can use the function [taxonomy_get_term_by_name](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name/7)

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_select/7

Interface: http://drupal.org/project/views